# Moving projects between MonoDevelop and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, monodevelop

I need to be able to open a project with MonoDevelop, work on it, save it, and then open the same project with Visual Studio 2012, work on that as well, save the changes, and open with MonoDevelop again.

How would I go about doing something like that? Is there some way to export a MonoDevelop project to Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoDevelop uses the same project and solution file format as Visual Studio so you should be able to switch between the two.

If in doubt use version control for your files then you can easily undo any changes.